# A Simple Question

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

May White mate in two? Good luck!

**Thomas Rayner Dawson, Tidskrift för Schack, 1923**

[image]

**Major Hint:**

> e1=N

Comment: I have some questions: 1. What side is white and what is black? Is white coming from above or below?  2. Is it only about two moves for white, or one white, one black, one white and that's a mate then?

Comment: I mean do the white pawns go up or down?

Comment: (ROT13) Juvgr - Oko5+. Oynpx - XkAr2. Juvgr - Dr1# **Edit:** Oh wait, if the white pawns go up, then black pawns go down, so... agh! Nevermind ;)

Answer (score 6):

The short answer to the question is

> yes, white can mate in 2

We must show that

> blacks last move must have been b7-b5, so a5xb6 e.p., Ke3 Qe2# wins.

To show this

> First note that White pawns have made at least 7 captures.  There are 7 black pieces missing, so therefore white pawns have made exactly 7 captures.

Then

> Note that the black pawn on c2 must have captured the only missing piece (a rook) on c2 from d3.

So

> There is no other move black could have just made other than with the b-pawn.
>  Looking at each possibility.  Keep in mind it has to be a black move, not a black capture because the only black capture had to be on c2 from d3 and could not have happened on this move.
>  1. Could the King have just moved to d3.  No. if a) Ke2-d3: how did the Q on d1 get there to give check?  b) Kd4-d3: how did the pawn on c3 get there to give check? c) Kc4-d3: the knight must have moved to e3 prior to block the bishop check, but how did the bishop get there then? Note that it could not have given a discovered check since on piece on the board could have been in the way AND we showed that all the pieces were taken by pawns and there would be no time to take it after a discovered check.
>  2. could any of the pawns have moved?  no, there are pieces from where they would have had to move from (remember, it could not have been a capture).
>  3. could one of the knights, bishop or rook have moved?  no, there are pieces from all possible squares they could have moved from except f3, but Nf3-e1 is impossible because it would have been giving check on f3.
>  4. could it have been a promotion? no.  I'll reword it again so maybe it will be easier to see. Note that 7 black pieces are missing and there were seven captures by white pawns (see above).
>  --   First, note that the original h pawn is on e5, d6, or c7, so it is responsible for 3, 4 or 5 of the total of 7 captures.
>  -- Second, the pawn on a5 or a3 must have come from b2 and is responsible for 1 of the 7 captures.  If a5 came from c2, then thats 2 captures.  c3 and c7 must have done a capture each and one must have come from the d file.  the pawn on d6 must have done at least one capture. and the h pawn did a minimum 3 captures.  That's already 8 captures, so impossible.  If a5 came from d2, then thats 3 captures, 3 minimum from the h pawn, d6 at least 1 capture and one of the c pawns captured at least once, so thats 8 captures already, so impossible.
>  -- Thirdly, if the h pawn ended up on c7, that's 5+1 captures, so only one other capture was made.  it must have been either the pawn on e4 or e5 but not both.  so the original e file pawn never left the e file, nor did the original c file pawn, so no pawn on e2 to promote to knight.
>  -- Fourthly, if the h pawn ended up on d6, that's 4+1 captures.  One of the other 2 captures was to the c file and the other to the e file, meaning the original e file pawn never left the e file, nor did the original c file pawn, so again no pawn on e2 to promote to knight.
>  -- Finally, if the h pawn ended up on e5 and a black pawn ended up on e2, then we know there were 3 pawn captures and 4 piece captures.  In that case the h pawn must have captured a piece on f4 and e5 since the black f and e pawn were not captured.  Also, the pawn on e4 had to capture a piece, since the black e pawn was not captured.  If the pawn on c7 came from d2, it captured one piece and the pawn on d6 captured one piece, since the black c and d pawns are on c6 and c2.  That would make 5 piece captures, which is not possible.  If the pawn on c7 came from d2, then for the same reason, it would have to make two piece captures, which is impossible.  So again, there could not be a pawn on e2 that could promote to a knight.
>  
> QED Thus, as stated, the b pawn had to make the last move.

So now

> Suppose the b-pawn came from b6 and not b7.  Then White played Bb7-a6+ before that and black has no legal moves that he could have made. Note that it could not have been a capture on a6 because all the black pieces were taken by pawns.  Therefore black just played b7-b5.

Finally

> The previous moves must have looked something like this:
>    1... d3xc2 (the white rook falls)
>    2. Nb6-c4+  Ke3-d3+
>    3. Nc4-e3+  then
>    3.  ...  b7-b5
>    4. a5xb6 e.p. +   Kd3xe3
>    5. Qe2#

Comment: I didn't quite understand how we are eliminating the possibility that black's last move was capturing a white rook on c6 by a black pawn on d7.

Comment: @ObiObi the white pawn on c3 could not have made a capture (they're accounted for with other pawns), so the the pawn on c2 must have made the one capture that black made

Comment: I think @SteveV has analysed all possible last moves for black except one - that it could have been a black pawn from e2 promoting to a knight on e1. This possibility has to be ruled out by noting that the hypothetical black pawn on e2 would be originally from e7 and one of the white pawns on e4 & e5 would be originally from e2. These two "original" pawns couldn't have crossed over without having more captures than are possible within the problem's scope.

Comment: @ObiObi i think that's a restatement of what i have already.  i'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: @SteveV 1. b4 a5 2. bxa5 g5 3. Bb2 g4 4. Nc3 g3 5. hxg3 Nf6 6. Rh6 Ne4 7. Nd5 Nc3 8. Rc1 Nb1 9. Ra6 e5 10. Nf6+ Ke7 11. e4 d5 12. c3 d4 13. Rc2 d3 14. Ra7 dxc2 15. Nh3 Na6 16. d4 c6 17. d5 Nc7 18. Ba6 Kd6 19. Qd3 Kc5 20. d6 Bh6 21. Ke2 Bd2 22. dxc7 h5 23. Ng5 Qd5 24. exd5 e4 25. a3 e3 26. Kf3 h4 27. Qe2 Bf5 28. Kf4 Rae8 29. Ra8 h3 30. Rc8 h2 31. d6 h1=R 32. Nd5 Rc1 33. f3 Be4 34. fxe4 b5 35. Qd1 Rh4+ 36. Kf5 Rf4+ 37. gxf4 Kc4 38. Nh7 Kd3 39. Kg5 f5 40. Nhf6 e2 41. Ne3 Re5 42. fxe5 e1=N

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer (needs better proof)

I wouldn't even know where to start with this, except that I just happened to look at an old puzzle that came up as Related.

> I couldn't find a safe move using the queen, bishops, or knights.  However, the puzzle I read is solved by capturing En passant, which led to (re)learning that move just before seeing this puzzle.

I think I have the moves required (and I hope my notation is right):

> ```
> 1. axb6e.p.+  Kxe3
> 2. Qe2#
> ```

My explanation is probably a bit clumsy/lacking though:

> This assumes that the last move by black was their b4 pawn moving to b6.  This would have been done to block the a6 bishop's check.
>
> I can't find a way for white to have moved the bishop into check, so I think they must have moved their c4 knight to e3.  This also might have been done to block the d2 bishop's check.
>
> If that was the case, there's no real way to have moved the bishop into check, so I think the king must have moved from e3 to d3, again moving out of check (from the knight at c4)?  I don't know why they didn't move to f2 though (seems to be a legal option?).
>
> As there's no way to 'block' a knight, it had to move into that position.  The only origin point I see is b6, so it must have moved from b6 to c4, and that's as far back as I can figure out.
>
> So the previous 4 moves would have been:
>
> ```
> Nc4+ Kd3
> Ne3+ b6
> ```

Attempted/partial proof of black's previous move:

> None of the other black pawns could have been moved last, as they would have come from occupied spaces.  The same goes for the knight on b1, the bishop, and the rook.
>
> The e5 knight's only unoccupied option would have had the white king in check, so that's not valid.
>
> The king couldn't have come from e2 since there's no other way for the white queen to have moved into that position (white queens can't jump).  The same goes for d4, as the white pawn at c3 couldn't have moved there on the same turn.  That only leaves c4 as a possibility, and I'm not sure how to rule that out.
>
> The remaining pawn could have actually come from either b6 or b7, and I'm not sure how to rule out b6.

Right now, I see these three moves as being the only ones black could have made:

> King from c4 to d3
> Pawn from b6 to b5
> Pawn from b7 to b5

Please let me know if I've misunderstood something, or if there are holes in my logic.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Understood.  I've added some partial proof, but my capabilities are likely not up to "beyond all doubt" level.